# ssh to predefined server works only after I ssh to it by typing the ip manually

Tags: ssh, networking

In my `~/.ssh/config` file I have this definition

```
Host limping
    HostName 192.168.1.102
    user <user>
```

When I type in terminal

```
ssh limping
```

I get the error

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.102 port 22: No route to host
```

Then, when I type

```
ssh <user>@192.168.1.102
```

The connection works, and I can connect by using `ssh limping` as well.

What is missing?

```
yotam@Orange:/tmp$ netstat -rn 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp2s0
```

The result of `netstat -a` are the same when the connection works or not.

```
yotam@Orange:/tmp$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:104308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:104308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11862688 (11.8 MB)  TX bytes:11862688 (11.8 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:fc:93:cd:c6:9d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.105  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9a05:8ee4:e73f:1be6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2526887 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1145245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2760597592 (2.7 GB)  TX bytes:193162848 (193.1 MB)


yotam@Orange:~/Applications/CondMount$ ssh -v limping
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/yotam/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/yotam/.ssh/config line 35: Applying options for limping
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.102 [192.168.1.102] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.102 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.102 port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the information from `netstat -rn`, and `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: Are there any other global options in your configuration that may affect this entry?

Comment: @TimKennedy I've added them, at the moment ``ssh`` works properly. Next time it will act up on my, I'll add them as well.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, there are no global settings.

Comment: What does ssh -v host give you?

Comment: @EdNeville I've added the output you requested.

Comment: Is interface wlp2s0 wired or wireless? At the point that the first `ssh` command fails, does any other networking command still work (for example `curl http://www.bbc.co.uk/` or do those fail too?

Comment: @roaima wlp2s0 is wireless, and curl works (and I can browse the web)

Comment: You can browse at the point when the `ssh` fails?

Comment: @roaima you mean browsing the internet? yes, I can't in fact, that's how I'm communicating with you guys.

Comment: No. I mean at the point during which your `ssh` is failing. Once the second `ssh` works I'm no longer interested, because internet access is clearly working by then.

Comment: If you do `ssh limping` twice do you have the same error the second time?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek hmm... I couldn't connect at all, not even a ping. I proceeded to reboot the router, and I still couldn't connect the machine. I then tested on the server ``ssh localhost`` and was able to connect. After that I was able to ssh from the remote machine.

Comment: @roaima I understand that you asked about the duration when I can't connect to the server, but what do you mean by browse? Just being in the internet?

Comment: @Yotam yes, exactly that. What I'd like to find out (if possible) is whether the "`ssh` can't connect" problem is one example of a more general network problem, where nothing can reach anywhere on the Internet, or whether it's specific to `ssh`.

Comment: @roaima, so in that case my answer is the one I gave before, I can connect to the internet. I think (I'll verify this again next time) that I can't ping my machine.

Comment: @roaima yes, I can browse the web.

Comment: OK. You gave `192.168.1.102` as the target IP address for the server that disappears, and `192.168.1.105` as your local client IP address. If you can browser the web at the same point that you can't get to the target server, then it's a problem on the target server and you need to identify what it is about that system's network connection that causes it to fail. Perhaps it's on wireless, or a broken switch. Or it's got a faulty NIC.

Comment: @roaima yes the server is on wireless, but I is less than a meter from the router and the connection is exceptionally bad. I also connected a USB that has the same problem. The server can browse the web while this is going, so I suspect it is not a bad connection, but something that is wrong with that machine configuration.

Comment: Please show us that configuration (in your question).

Comment: @roaima which configuration do you mean?

Comment: The machine configuration you suspect is wrong

Comment: @roaima I suspect that the problematic configuration is on the server, but I'm not sure which file to open.